# Solve equation involving error function

Tags: analysis, error-function

I am trying to solve this equation for $\mu$
$$
(2a-1) \mu \cdot \mathrm{erf}\left( \frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right) + \frac{2\sigma \cdot (2a-1) \cdot e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2 \sigma^2}} }{\sqrt{2\pi}} + \mu=0
$$
with  $0 \le a \le 1$ and $\sigma > 0$. Clearly, when $a=\frac{1}{2}$ the first two terms cancel out and the solution is $\mu=0$.

I can find the solution numerically, and I think it should be possible to express the solution as a linear function of $\sigma$, something like $\mu=f(a)\cdot \sigma$, with $f(0.5)=0$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I can solve it numerically" - Let it stay like this.

Comment: Divide the equation by $\sigma$, put $x = \dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}$, and put $y = 2 a -1$:

$$
y x \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) + \frac{2 y\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2\pi}} + x=0
$$

Comment: Interesting question but I think there is no way to solve it analytically.